# How many PHP scripts can run concurrently via http request?

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, concurrency

I know PHP scripts can run concurrently, but I notice that when I run a script and then run another script after it. It waits for the first to finish and then it does what it has to do?

Is there an Apache config I have to change or do I use a different browser or something?!!

Thanks all

### EDIT

If I go to a different browser, I can access the page/PHP script I need?! Is this limiting the number of requests by browser? Apache?

Comment: This is a question for serverfault or superuser I guess.

Comment: On the other hand it is a fairly technical question about the execution of a programming language.

Comment: I don't have any problems with my server. Just the PHP scripts running on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things comes to mind:

1. HTTP 1.1 has a recommend maximum limit of 2 simultaneous connections to any given domain.  This would exhibit the problem where you can only open one page on a site at a time unless you switch browsers.
   Edit: This is usually enforced by the client, not the server
2. If your site uses sessions, you'll find out that only one page will load at a time...
   ...unless you call [session_write_close()](http://php.net/session_write_close), at which point the second page can now open the now-unlocked session file.

Comment: Very Interesting. I didn't know those two facts. What if the second request isn't going to write any session data but use it. PHP pauses regardless is there is a session_start anywhere in the script?

Comment: I believe session_write_close() still allows you to read session values, but I haven't tested it (we don't use PHP where I work).

For point 1, you can't really... it's the client that does this.  On Firefox, I believe the FasterFox plugin can do it.  IE uses a registry key: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402

Comment: +1 because it's probably #2. I've never known any web server actually enforce #1.

Comment: @Ben James: Yes, #1 is usually enforced by the client.  I've added a note about that to the answer.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - I would use that function but the thing is the first script takes quite a while  to finish and has to make use of session variables throughout. So the second has to just wait. I probably have to rewrite some parts of my script.

Comment: @R. Bemrose Would I have the same problem using a database based session? Or will the DB sort out the problem of concurrency? It should allow me to read multiple times without changing variables I guess?

Comment: @Abs: I'm not sure.  I haven't really worked with PHP's database-based sessions.  I would assume a DB-based session wouldn't lock, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you run php under fastcgi you can probably avoid this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this problem with apache / php, the project I work on runs 3 iframes each of which is a php script + the main page, apache handles all 4 at the same time.

You may want to check your apache configuration and see how the threading is setup.

This article may help:
http://www.devside.net/articles/apache-performance-tuning